# Prime ideals of the matrix ring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have to do the following question:

Given a unital ring $R$ and a natural number $n$ $\geq 1$, identify (with proof) the prime ideals of the matrix ring $\mathbb{M}_{n}(R)$.

I understand the theory, but putting it all together is proving difficult.

I understand that the prime ideals of $\mathbb{M}_{n}(R)$ should be $\mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{P})$.

Can anyone suggest any steps as to how to prove this?

Comment: Is it $R$ a commutative ring?

Comment: No, just a unital ring

Comment: Commutativity shouldn't matter...

Comment: But there is a different definition of prime ideals in non-commutative rings, right? @rschwieb

Comment: I need to prove $AB \subseteq \mathbb{M}_{n}(AB)$, and its reverse inclusion, I think, where A and B are $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)$ and $\mathbb{M}_{n}(B)$, respectively.

Comment: @Charter Yes... and that is, presumably, the one meant if the poster is talking about prime ideals in noncommutative rings. It's not really "different" so much as it is "more general."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to convince yourself that $M_n(A)M_n(B)=M_n(AB)$ for any two ideals $A,B$ of $R$.

After that it's just straightforward checking:

If $P$ is prime, then what does $M_n(A)M_n(B)\subseteq M_n(P)$ imply about $M_n(A)$ or $M_n(B)$?

If $M_n(P)$ is prime (and you don't know if $P$ is yet), then take two ideals $A,B$ and suppose $AB\subseteq P$ and ask what that means for $M_n(A)$ and $M_n(B)$.  Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: I've got some of the way. I've got that if $A$ = $a_{1} + ... + a_{n}$ and $B$ = $b_{1} + ... + b_{n}$, then AB = $a_{1}b_{1} + ... + a_{n}b_{n}$, and for $\mathbb{M}_{n}(AB) = \sum a_{ik}b_{kj}$, I have $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A) =  a_{ik}$ and $\mathbb{M}_{n}(B) =  a_{kj}$. Is this what you meant by 'battering notation'?

Comment: @Dazzler95 don't worry about the battering comment: I guess it is not really an abuse of notation.

Comment: For the trivial containment, would you just use that $AB = A \times B$? I don't see how it's obvious.

Comment: Sorry, looking back again I see I typoed. The direction $M_n(AB)\supseteq M_n(A)M_n(B)$ is the trivial one, and I was going to ask you to work on $M_n(AB)\subseteq M_n(A)M_n(B)$

Comment: OK, and is it trivial because of the details I've put in my first comment? Is it just a matter of matrix multiplication?

Comment: @Dazzler95 There are several typos which I don't agree with, but yes, matrix multiplication. For the other direction, pick a matrix $C$ in $M_n(AB)$ and decompose $C$ into a sum of matrices which are nonzero only on one position, and then further so that the single nonzero entry is broken down to the form $ab$ for some $a\in A, b\in B$. Show that all of these can be written as a product of something in $M_n(A)$ with something in $M_n(B)$.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your argument, I'm just finding it difficult to formulate, Let me take a shot at it. If I have a matrix with its entry in the first row and first column c, and the rest of it 0, and say that is the product of two other matrices a and b, each with corresponding first entries, then I have that $c = a \times b$. I'm struggling with the next part though, which is to "show all of these can be written as a product of something in $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)$ with something in $\mathbb{M}_{n}(B)$". I'm pretty sure I can't just generalise and say that's enough.

Comment: @Dazzler95 I'm not really sure you can say you understand the part about $c=a\times b$ and not understand the second part about being a product of things in $M_n(A)$ and $M_n(B)$. The definition of $M_n(A)M_n(B)$ is: $\{\sum A_iB_i\mid A_i\in M_n(A),B_i\in M_n(B)\}$. I'm just saying you need to prove that an arbitrary element of $M_n(AB)$ is of that form to show the reverse containment

Comment: For an illustration of the most basic case, let let $a\in A$, $b\in B$ and consider $\begin{bmatrix}0&ab\\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix}$. This can be written as $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in M_n(A)M_n(B)$. My contention is that since you can do this for all the simple cases, you can actually do it for anything in $M_n(AB)$.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. So is the next step to assume that P is prime, and then ask what that says about the matrices of A and B?

Comment: @Dazzler95 No, assume $P$ prime and show that $M_n(P)$ is prime. Then the reverse implication.

Comment: I've got an argument, and I hope it works. Let P be prime, then $ AB \subseteq P \Rightarrow  A \subseteq P$ or $B \subseteq P$. Then $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)\mathbb{M}_{n}(B)=\mathbb{M}_{n}(AB)  \triangleright \mathbb{M}_{n}(R)$. And $\mathbb{M}_{n}(AB) \subseteq  \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{P})$. Further, $\Rightarrow \mathbb{M}_{n}(A)\cdot \mathbb{M}_{n}(B) \subseteq \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{P})$

Comment: Then, as one of $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)$ or $\mathbb{M}_{n}(B)$ is contained within the matrix of prime elements, then either $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)$ or $\mathbb{M}_{n}(B)$ is a prime ideal. Does this work?

Comment: @Dazzler95 No, because you are not started at the right place or headed to the right thing. Starting point: Suppose $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and also that $M_n(A)M_n(B)\subseteq M_n(P)$. Ending point: $M_n(A)$ or $M_n(B)$ is contained in $M_n(P)$. That would prove $M_n(P)$ is prime. (Then there is the other direction but we'll worry about that when you get to it.)

Comment: OK. So given $M_{n}(A)\cdot M_{n}(B) = M_{n}(AB)$, can you just say that $AB =P$? And then if $P$ is a product of $AB$, then $a$ or $b$ is contained within $p$, where they are elements of the corresponding matrix?

Comment: You can say that $AB\subseteq P$, which, by the definition of a prime ideal, implies that $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$. And that implies $M_n(A)\subseteq M_n(P)$ or $M_n(B)\subseteq M_n(P)$.

Comment: OK, thanks. So the reverse inclusion is that given $\mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{P})$ is prime, show what that means for $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)$ and $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)$. Am I right that if $AB\subseteq P$, then $\mathbb{M}_{n}(A)\mathbb{M}_{n}(B)\subseteq \mathbb{M}_{n}(P)$?

Comment: @Dazzler95 That is correct. And I'm sure you see the final step.

Comment: OK, so to finish then, I have $\mathbb{M}_{n}(AB)\subseteq \mathbb{M}_{n}(P)$ and $\mathbb{M}_{n}(AB)=\mathbb{M}_{n}(P)$. Would that be enough to identify the prime ideals of the matrix ring?

Comment: No, $M_n(AB)=M_n(P)$ almost never happens, and I'm a bit puzzled why you keep shoehorning it into your reasoning. It's not necessary. You need to reread the definition of what a prime ideal is a few times until you actually internalize it. I feel a bit like you are not listening to it.

Comment: The final step I was alluding to, by the way, because I don't want to discuss this any more, is "so either $M_n(A)\subseteq M_n(P)$ in which case $A\subseteq P$, or $M_n(B)\subseteq M_n(P)$, in which case $B\subseteq P$, and we have shown that $P$ is prime."

Comment: I do understand what a prime ideal is, but this is my first time doing abstract algebra. I haven't even done Group Theory before, which some of my classmates have, and I think they are finding it easier. Thanks again, and hopefully I didn't take up too much of your time

Comment: @Dazzler95 no problem: look forward to working with you again, and hopefully the pieces start falling into place.