# If $ R $ is a prime ring then $ M_{n}(R) $ is prime ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

If $ R $ is a prime ring then $ M_{n}(R) $ is prime ring.

SOLUTION

Let $ S=M_{n}(R) $ and $ aSb=0 $. For all $ r∈R $ say that $ s=re_{ij} $. So $ (are_{ij}b)_{kl}=0 $. I obtain $ (a_{k1}+a_{k2}+...+a_{kn})r(b_{1l}+b_{2l}+...+b_{nl})=0 $ and since R is prime $ (a_{k1}+a_{k2}+...+a_{kn})=0 $ or $ (b_{1l}+b_{2l}+...+b_{nl})=0 $. But, I don't know how can I say that each $ a_{ki}=0 $ whenever $ i=1,2,...,n $

Comment: @buse The inclusion of your attempt has much improved the question by showing us the method you wanted to use, and how far you've gotten with it. Thanks for taking the time to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean that if for all $a,b∈R$, if $aRb=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$ satifies then we say that $R$ is prime ring ( I mean not as ideal ). I want to use this definition to solve problem

It's a little messy looking, but perhaps no more work than translating everything to ideals and solving it as in [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2018727/29335).

Let's start with $aSb=\{0\}$ and work with the unit matrices as you were. Remember that $e_{jj}ae_{kk}$ is going to yield $a_{jk}e_{jk}$, the matrix you get when you replace everything in $a$ except the $i,j$ entry with zero, $a_{jk}\in R$.

We can say that $\{0\}=e_{ii}aSbe_{mm}\supseteq e_{ii}a(e_{jj}e_{jj}Se_{kk}e_{kk})be_{mm}$ for every $i,j,k,m$. The important stuff you want from the last expression is rewritten here:

$$
\{0\}=(e_{ii}ae_{jj})(e_{jj}Se_{kk})(e_{kk}be_{mm})=(a_{ij}e_{ij})(S_{jk}e_{jk})(b_{km}e_{km})=a_{ij}S_{jk}b_{km}e_{im}
$$

By a little abuse of notation, I'm writing $S$ both as if it were a matrix and as if it were a set of matrices. The symbol $S_{jk}$ should be accordingly read as "the set of $jk$ entries of elements in $S$". But this is just the set $\{re_{jk}\mid r\in R\}$.

Now if both $a$ and $b$ were nonzero on some element, you could pick $i,j,k,m$ such that $a_{ij}$ and $b_{km}$ are both nonzero. As discussed above, the $S_{jk}$ ranges all over $R$, so the far right of the equation is saying that $a_{ij}Rb_{km}=\{0\}$ in $R$. But this is a contradiction if $R$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

A two-sided ideal of $M_n(R)$ has the form $M_n(I)$, meaning the matrices with coefficients in $I$, where $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$.

Prove that $M_n(I)M_n(J)=M_n(IJ)$ and you're done.

Comment: How can I use this equation to show prime ring?

Comment: @BuseEralp Prime means "if $IJ=0$ for $I$ and $J$ ideals of $R$, then either $I=0$ or $J=0$”.

Comment: I mean that if for all $ a,b \in R  $ $ aRb=0 $ then $a=0  $ or $ b=0 $ satifies then we say that $ R $ is prime ring ( I mean not as ideal ). I want to use this definition to solve problem.