# Ideals in $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I’m trying to work on the problem that asks to find all the ideals, (maximal and prime ideals) of $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, the ring of all $2\times2$ matrices with integers entries.

So, I found that the set of all ideals of $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is essentially $M_{2}(n\mathbb{Z})$, where $n=0,1,...$. However, when I go on and find the prime and maximal ideals, I am not sure. Intuitively, I would say the $0$ matrix and $M_{2}(p\mathbb{Z})$, where $p$ is prime are prime ideals of $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Are they actually prime ideals of this ring? If not, I would really appreciate any hint or suggestion.

One more thing to make sure is that, is $0$ a prime ideal? Since the definition state that a prime ideal has to be a proper ideal of the ring, which $0$ is indeed a proper ideal.

Comment: If the product of two matrices is zero, is one of the matrices necessarily zero?

Comment: I would say no. Then, is the $M_{2}(p\mathbb{Z})$ correct?

Comment: No, there's the same issue with $M_2(p\mathbb{Z})$. In fact the same counterexample works for all of these ideals: $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 oh, I just figured it out. Then, is it proper to say that there is no prime ideals, using the general counterexample?

Comment: I have to admit it's been some time since I've thought much about non-commutative algebra. I am not entirely sure if the usual definition for commutative rings carries over. You should check whatever definition your book is using.

Comment: @carmichael561 it’s totally fine, thanks! I think I got the idea of this problem. Just do not sure that $M_{2}(n\mathbb{Z})$ are the only ideals of the ring.

Comment: That is correct, provided that "ideal" means "two-sided ideal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the same as [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015769/29335), except that you can go further and say that the maximal ideals of $M_2(\mathbb Z)$ correspond to the maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z$. The prime ideals are of the form $M_2(\{0\})$ and $M_2(p\mathbb Z)$ for primes $p\in\mathbb Z$, and they're all maximal except for the former one.

Since you are talking about the prime ideals of a matrix ring, which is noncommutative, I assume you're using the [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings) of "prime ideal" for noncommutative rings.

Comment: I’m sorry but how can $M_{2}(0)$ and $M_{2}(p\mathbb{Z})$ are prime? Since you can choose two matrices that are not in those two rings and still give matrices in them. For example, the matrix (1, 0; 0, 1)*(0, 1; 1, 0) = (0 0; 0 0).

Comment: @Harry You need to read the definitions I linked to. That is not the standard definition for “prime ideal” in a noncommutative ring.